Complete payment in amazon pay
On my e-commerce website i'm trying to implement amazon pay. Here i've created the checkout session successfully, but when I choose payment in amazon it comes back to my website but I want to proceed making payment in the amazon instead of coming back to my website. I want the process similar to express integration button which amazon provides only for fixed payment. I'm very confused and got stuck in this process. Please kindly help me to solve this problem.
load button:
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 5%;">
                <?php $this->load->view('widgets/payment/amazon_pay_payment'); ?>
            </div>

amazon_pay.php
<div class="row">
     
    <div class="col-md-12">
       
        <div id="amazonPayButtonContainer"></div>
       


        <!-- Amazon Pay script start -->
        <script src="https://static-na.payments-amazon.com/checkout.js"></script>
<!--                <button id="placeOrderButton" >Place Order</button>-->

        <script>
            console.log('Script loaded');
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                console.log('DOMContentLoaded event fired');
                console.log('DOMContentLoaded event fired');
    
    // Extract the amazonCheckoutSessionId from the URL
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const amazonCheckoutSessionId = urlParams.get('amazonCheckoutSessionId');
    console.log('Amazon Checkout Session ID:', amazonCheckoutSessionId);
                const orderReferenceId = '<?php echo $custom; ?>';
                <?php
                $this->load->library('amazon_pay_lib');
//                $checkoutSession = $this->amazon_pay_lib->createCheckoutSession(
//                    array(
//                        'checkoutReviewReturnUrl' => g('base_url') . "checkout/notify",
//                        'oid' => $order_id,
//                        'code' => md5($order_id),
//                        'payment_status' => 'Completed',
//                        'custom' => $order_id
//                    ),
//                    array('storeId' => 'amzn1.application-oa2-client.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
//                );
//                $checkoutSession = $this->amazon_pay_lib->createCheckoutSession(
//                    array(
//                        'checkoutReviewReturnUrl' => g('base_url') . "checkout/notify", 
//                        'oid' => $order_id,
//                        'code' => md5($order_id),
//                        'payment_status' => 'Completed',
//                        'custom' => $order_id
//                    ),
//                    array('storeId' => 'amzn1.application-oa2-client.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
//                );

$checkoutSession = $this->amazon_pay_lib->createCheckoutSession(
                    array('checkoutReviewReturnUrl' => 'https://example.com/checkout/step3?oid=472',
            'checkoutResultReturnUrl' => 'https://localhost/store/checkout_result'),
                    array('storeId' => 'amzn1.application-oa2-client.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                );

                $payload = $checkoutSession['payload'];
                $signature = $checkoutSession['signature'];
                ?>

                console.log('Payload:', <?php echo json_encode($payload); ?>);
                console.log('Signature:', <?php echo json_encode($signature); ?>);
                
                
                

                const amazonPayButton = amazon.Pay.renderButton('#amazonPayButtonContainer', {
                    checkoutMode: 'Web/PuppetCheckout',
                    merchantId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
                    publicKeyId: 'LIVE-XXXXXXXXXXXX',
                    ledgerCurrency: 'USD',
                    checkoutLanguage: 'en_US',
                    productType: 'PayOnly',
//                    sandbox: true,
                    placement: 'Cart',
                    buttonColor: 'Gold',
                    estimatedOrderAmount: {
                        "amount": '<?php echo json_encode($amount + $tax); ?>',
                        "currencyCode": "USD"
                    },
                    createCheckoutSessionConfig: {
                        storeId: 'amzn1.application-oa2-client.XXXXXXXXXXXX',
                        payloadJSON: '<?php echo $checkoutSession['payload']; ?>',
                        signature: '<?php echo $checkoutSession['signature']; ?>',
                        algorithm: 'AMZN-PAY-RSASSA-PSS-V2'
                    },
                    merchantMetadata: {
                        'merchantNote': 'Your merchant note',
                        'merchantReferenceId': '<?php echo $custom; ?>'
                    },
                    onError: function (error) {
                        console.log('onError callback:', error);
                        console.log('Error:', error.getErrorCode(), error.getErrorMessage());
                    },
                    authorization: function() {
            loginOptions = {scope: " payments:widget", popup: true};
            authRequest = amazon.Login.authorize (loginOptions, function(t) {
                    // console.log(t.access_token);
                    // console.log(t.expires_in);
                     console.log('checkout:', amazonCheckoutSessionId);
//                    showWalletWidget(null);
//                fetch('<?php echo base_url('amazon_pay_lib/getShippingAndPaymentInfo'); ?>', {
//                            method: 'POST',
//                            headers: {
//                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
//                            },
//                            body: JSON.stringify({
//                                checkoutSessionId: checkoutSessionId,
//                            }),
//                        })
//                            .then(response => response.json())
//                            .then(data => {
//                                console.log('Shipping and Payment Info:', data);
//                            })
//                            .catch(error => {
//                                console.error('Error fetching shipping and payment info:', error);
//                            });
                        
                });
          }
                    
//                    onAuthorize: function (authorizeResult) {
//                        console.log('onAuthorize callback:', authorizeResult);
//                        console.log('Authorization successful:', authorizeResult);
//                        const checkoutSessionId = authorizeResult.details.checkoutSessionId;
////                         document.getElementById('placeOrderButton').disabled = false;
//
////                        fetch('<?php echo base_url('amazon_pay_lib/getShippingAndPaymentInfo'); ?>', {
////                            method: 'POST',
////                            headers: {
////                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
////                            },
////                            body: JSON.stringify({
////                                checkoutSessionId: checkoutSessionId,
////                            }),
////                        })
////                            .then(response => response.json())
////                            .then(data => {
////                                console.log('Shipping and Payment Info:', data);
////                            })
////                            .catch(error => {
////                                console.error('Error fetching shipping and payment info:', error);
////                            });
//                        
//                      
//                    }
                    
                });
                
              
                
            });
            
        
            

        </script>
        
        <!-- Amazon Pay script end -->
    </div>
</div>



Amazon_pay_lib.php
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once FCPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

use Amazon\Pay\API\Client;
 
  

class Amazon_pay_lib {
    private $client;
    private $privateKeyPath;  // Add this line
    
    public function __construct() {
        $this->privateKeyPath = FCPATH . 'AmazonPay_LIVE-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pem';
        $this->initializeAmazonPayClient();

    }

    private function initializeAmazonPayClient() {
        $config = array(
            'public_key_id' => 'LIVE-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
            'private_key' => file_get_contents($this->privateKeyPath),
            'region' => 'us',
//            'sandbox' => true,
            'algorithm' => 'AMZN-PAY-RSASSA-PSS-V2',
        );

        
        
        try {
            $this->client = new Client($config);
            
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            die('Error initializing Amazon Pay client: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }   
    }
    
  
    
   
    
   
    
    public function getAccessToken() {
    try {
        $clientId = 'amzn1.application-oa2-client.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        $clientSecret = 'amzn1.oa2-cs.v1.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // Replace with your client secret
        $credentials = new \Amazon\Pay\API\Credentials($clientId, $clientSecret);

        $payloadData = [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'scope' => 'payments:transactions_read',
        ];

        $payload = new \Amazon\Pay\API\Request\AuthorizeFromCredentials($payloadData, $credentials);
        $response = $this->client->getAccessToken($payload);

        if ($response['status'] === 200) {
            $data = json_decode($response['response'], true);
            return $data['access_token'];
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Error obtaining access token. Status: ' . $response['status']);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
}
    
    public function updateCheckoutAndCompletePayment($checkoutSessionId) {
        try {
            // Update the checkout session (if needed)
            // You can implement logic here to update the checkout session
            
            // Complete the payment
            $result = $this->client->completeCheckoutSession($checkoutSessionId);
            
            if ($result['status'] === 200) {
                // Payment completed successfully
                return true;
            } else {
                // Payment completion failed
                return false;
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle exceptions
            die('Error updating checkout session and completing payment: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    public function completePayment() {
    try {
        // Get the checkout session ID from the request
        $checkoutSessionId = $_POST['checkoutSessionId'];

        // Call the method to update checkout session and complete payment
        $paymentCompleted = $this->updateCheckoutAndCompletePayment($checkoutSessionId);

        if ($paymentCompleted) {
            // Payment completed successfully
            echo json_encode(['success' => true]);
        } else {
            // Payment completion failed
            echo json_encode(['success' => false]);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Handle exceptions
        echo json_encode(['error' => 'Error completing payment: ' . $e->getMessage()]);
    }
}


    
//    public function getShippingAndPaymentInfo($checkoutSessionId, $headers = array())
//{
//    try {
//        $result = $this->client->getCheckoutSession($checkoutSessionId, $headers);
//
//        // ... (rest of the method remains the same)
//        if ($result['status'] === 200) {
//                $response = json_decode($result['response'], true);
//                $checkoutSessionState = $response['statusDetails']['state'];
//                $chargeId = $response['chargeId'];
//                $chargePermissionId = $response['chargePermissionId'];
//
//                // Handle other response data as needed
//                $buyerName = $response['buyer']['name'];
//                $buyerAddress = $response['buyer']['shippingAddress'];
//
//                // Return the shipping and payment info
//                return array(
//                    'checkoutSessionState' => $checkoutSessionState,
//                    'chargeId' => $chargeId,
//                    'chargePermissionId' => $chargePermissionId,
//                    'buyerName' => $buyerName,
//                    'buyerAddress' => $buyerAddress,
//                    // Add other data as needed
//                );
//            } else {
//                // Handle the error
//                return array(
//                    'error' => 'Error fetching shipping and payment info. Status: ' . $result['status'],
//                );
//            }
//    } catch (\Exception $e) {
//        // Handle the exception
//        return array(
//            'error' => 'Exception: ' . $e->getMessage(),
//        );
//    }
//}


    
    public function getShippingAndPaymentInfo($checkoutSessionId) {
        try {
            $result = $this->client->getCheckoutSession($checkoutSessionId);

            if ($result['status'] === 200) {
                $response = json_decode($result['response'], true);
                $checkoutSessionState = $response['statusDetails']['state'];
                $chargeId = $response['chargeId'];
                $chargePermissionId = $response['chargePermissionId'];

                // Handle other response data as needed
                $buyerName = $response['buyer']['name'];
                $buyerAddress = $response['buyer']['shippingAddress'];

                // Return the shipping and payment info
                return array(
                    'checkoutSessionState' => $checkoutSessionState,
                    'chargeId' => $chargeId,
                    'chargePermissionId' => $chargePermissionId,
                    'buyerName' => $buyerName,
                    'buyerAddress' => $buyerAddress,
                    // Add other data as needed
                );
            } else {
                // Handle the error
                return array(
                    'error' => 'Error fetching shipping and payment info. Status: ' . $result['status'],
                );
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle the exception
            return array(
                'error' => 'Exception: ' . $e->getMessage(),
            );
        }
    }
    public function generateAmazonPaySignature($payload) {
        try {
            return $this->client->generateButtonSignature($payload);
            echo $signature . "\n";
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            die('Error generating Amazon Pay signature: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

  public function createCheckoutSession($payload, $headers = array()) {
    try {
//           echo 'Request Payload: ' . json_encode($payload) . '<br>';

    // Echo the headers data for debugging
//    echo 'Request Headers: ' . json_encode($headers) . '<br>';
        // Log the payload data before making the request
//    file_put_contents(FCPATH . 'file.log', 'Request Payload: ' . json_encode($payload) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

        // Log the headers data before making the request
//        file_put_contents(FCPATH . 'file.log', 'Request Headers: ' . json_encode($headers) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

        
        $amazonpay_config = array(
            'public_key_id' => 'LIVE-XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'private_key'   => file_get_contents($this->privateKeyPath),
            'region'        => 'us',
//            'sandbox'       => true,
            'algorithm'     => 'AMZN-PAY-RSASSA-PSS-V2'
        );

        $client = new \Amazon\Pay\API\Client($amazonpay_config);
            $headers = array('x-amz-pay-idempotency-key' => uniqid());
        $checkoutSession = $client->createCheckoutSession($payload, $headers);
        $payload = json_encode([
                'storeId' => 'amzn1.application-oa2-client.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                'webCheckoutDetails' => [
                    'checkoutReviewReturnUrl' => $payload['checkoutReviewReturnUrl'],
                ],
            ]);
$signature = $client->generateButtonSignature($payload);

// Debug statements
file_put_contents(FCPATH . 'file.log', 'Payload: ' . $payload . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents(FCPATH . 'file.log', 'Signature: ' . $signature . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

return [
    'payload' => $payload,
    'signature' => $signature,
];
        // Check if the 'x-amz-pay-authtoken' key exists in the headers
//        if (isset($checkoutSession['headers']['x-amz-pay-authtoken'])) {
//            // Obtain the auth token from the response headers
//            $authToken = $checkoutSession['headers']['x-amz-pay-authtoken'];
//
//            // Include the auth token in the headers for subsequent requests
//            $headers['x-amz-pay-authtoken'] = $authToken;
//        } else {
//            // Handle the case where the key is not set (perhaps log a warning)
//            // $headers['x-amz-pay-authtoken'] will remain unset in this case
//        }
 $responsePayload = $checkoutSession['payload'];
        $responseSignature = $checkoutSession['signature'];

//        return [
//            'payload' => $responsePayload,
//            'signature' => $responseSignature,
//        ];
//        return $checkoutSession;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
         echo 'Error creating checkout session: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br>';
                
        file_put_contents(FCPATH . 'file.log', 'Error creating checkout session: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);


        die('Error creating checkout session: ' . $e->getMessage());
    } catch (\ValueError $ve) {
        file_put_contents(FCPATH . 'file.log', 'Error: ' . $ve->getMessage() . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
 echo 'Error: ' . $ve->getMessage() . '<br>';
        die('Error: ' . $ve->getMessage());
    }
}
    
    public function updateCheckoutAndCompleteAmazonPayment($checkoutSessionId) {
        try {
            $result = $this->client->completeCheckoutSession($checkoutSessionId);
            if ($result['status'] === 200) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            die('Error updating checkout session and completing payment: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    
   public function updateCheckoutSession() {
    try {
        // Get the checkout session ID and updated payload from the request
        $checkoutSessionId = $_POST['checkoutSessionId'];
        $updatedPayload = json_decode($_POST['updatedPayload'], true);

        $amazonpay_config = array(
            'public_key_id' => 'LIVE-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'private_key' => file_get_contents($this->privateKeyPath),
            'region' => 'us',
            'algorithm' => 'AMZN-PAY-RSASSA-PSS-V2'
        );

        $client = new \Amazon\Pay\API\Client($amazonpay_config);

        // Update the checkout session with the new payload
        $result = $client->updateCheckoutSession($checkoutSessionId, $updatedPayload);

        if ($result['status'] === 200) {
            // Checkout session updated successfully
            $response = json_decode($result['response'], true);
            echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'response' => $response]);
        } else {
            // Checkout session update failed
            echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'error' => $result['response']]);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Handle exceptions
        echo json_encode(['error' => 'Error updating checkout session: ' . $e->getMessage()]);
    }
}

    
   
    
 
    
    



}
?>


I've generated the checkout session successfully but i dont know how to proceed making payment. I dont want to come back to my website and proceed again instead once the payment method chosen it should proceed on the amazon itself and make payment.

To achieve a direct checkout without redirecting back to the original site before the payment is complete, you want to set the webCheckoutDetails.checkoutMode parameter of your CheckoutSession  to ProcessOrder.
Please not that you are required to also send the addressDetails in this case unless you are in PayOnly mode.
Also you should leave the checkoutReviewReturnUrl empty.
For reference: https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/amazon-pay-api-v2/checkout-session.html
